# Where should we use fetch_assoc method?

Tags: php, oop, object, mysqli, foreach

I started this little blog project and I think I have just made a mistake by not including `fetch_assoc` method.
This is the code:

```
$data = new database();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post ";
 $article = $data->select($sql);
 foreach ($article as  $value) : ?>
 <div class="blog-post">
<h2 class="blog-post-title"><?= $value["blog_title"]; ?></h2>
```

and this is how the select methode look like:

```
public function select($sql){
     $result = $this->con->query($sql) or die($this->con->error.__LINE__);
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        return $result;
     }else {
       return false;
     }
}
```

I want to know why it has worked for me (the title of the blog shows up correctly) although I have forgotten to put the `fetch_assoc` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `fetch_assoc()` most of the time. If you are writing some kind of abstraction class around mysqli then you should never need to use any of mysqli functions directly.

`mysqli:query()` returns an object of type `mysqli_result` which is iterable. This means you can use `foreach` loop to iterate over it.

I need to point out that you are still following some bad programming practices. You should never use `or die($this->con->error.__LINE__)`. This is a terrible coding practice and completely unnecessary. Instead, you should enable proper error reporting. See [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Your `select()` method should return only an array. This would make your code much easier and less error-prone. So rewrite your `select()` function to this:

```
public function select($sql){
    return $this->con->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

As you can see the whole functionality is a single line of code, which means your `select()` method is not very useful. You can replace it with something more generic instead. This way you avoid a lot of code repetition.

```
public function executeQuery(string $sql, array $params = []): ?array {
    // Prepare/bind/execute
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    if ($params) {
        $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($params)), ...$params);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    // If it was a select query which gives result then return results in an array
    if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
        return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    }
    // If it is INSERT/UPDATE then return null instead of array
    return null;
}
```

Of course this method should not be part of your model. It should be part of a dedicated class for database communication. You can then create a single instance of it in your application and pass it to your model.

Comment: thanks @Dharman  for your reply but ,`bind_param(str_repeat("s",count($params)), ...$params) ` we can have other things like integer, so we need **d** instead of **s** and  for ``$params`` i think we need a loop for having all the parameters putted as an array in the ``executeQuery methode``

Comment: @FaresArs 99.99% of the time you don't need anything other than string. But if you do need to specify the type manually then I recommend reading this short article: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple